# How do I catch psql errors in node?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm currently writing a backend node server with a Postgresql database where I've attempted to make a registration API set-up. I want to be able to catch errors that are caused by unique constraint violations. How can I do that?

```
function createMember(body, callBack){  
  // This function adds someone who is newly registered to the database.

  var id;
  var sql = 'INSERT INTO member (fname, lname, phone, email, age, gender) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING id;';
  db.query(sql, [body.fname, body.lname, body.phone, body.email, body.age, body.gender]).then(res => {
      id = res.rows[0].id;
      if (id) {
        callBack(body);
        console.log("New member with id: " + id);
      }
  }).catch(e => {
      if (the error is a unique constraint violation){
        console.log("\n ERROR! \n Individual with name: " + body.fname + " " + body.lname + " and phone #: " + body.phone + " is a duplicate member. \n");
        callBack("Duplicate");
        return;
      }
      console.log("\n \n ERROR! \n Individual with name: " + body.fname + " " + body.lname + " and phone #: " + body.phone + " could not be added. \n", e);
      callBack(false);
      return e;
  })
}
```

Comment: Where is db coming from and does it already do the mapping you show below?

Comment: `db` is the pg client that is connected to the database. Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "mapping". If you mean to ask if the database is populated in that manner, then yes.

Comment: But what is the name of the program that is supplying db?  By mapping I mean it may already supply error names that you can filter on instead of looking up codes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the name of the program that is supplying `db`... isn't it just the pg client. Pg is a node module that can be used to connect the node instance as a client to the postgresql database. The `db` client is an object.

Comment: Also, if pg (Postgres) supplies a mapping with keys to the codes, I'm more than happy to use that but I haven't seen them. So far as I know, they give us the codes to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So since I haven't found any answers to this, I think I can share mine.

Each error in Postgresql has an error code which can be found at:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/errcodes-appendix.html

If you look at the error you get when there is a unique key violation you may notice that the code is "23505".

Simply add a check in your catch block to see if the error has a code of "23505".

```
function createMember(body, callBack){  
  // This function adds someone who is newly registered to the database.

  var id;
  var sql = 'INSERT INTO member (fname, lname, phone, email, age, gender) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING id;';
  db.query(sql, [body.fname, body.lname, body.phone, body.email, body.age, body.gender]).then(res => {
      id = res.rows[0].id;
      if (id) {
        callBack(body);
        console.log("New member with id: " + id);
      }
  }).catch(e => {
      if (e.code == '23505'){
        console.log("\n ERROR! \n Individual with name: " + body.fname + " " + body.lname + " and phone #: " + body.phone + " is a duplicate member. \n");
        callBack("Duplicate");
        return;
      }
      console.log("\n \n ERROR! \n Individual with name: " + body.fname + " " + body.lname + " and phone #: " + body.phone + " cannot be added. \n", e);
      callBack(false);
      return e;
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach! I took it in a different direction (I had unique constraints on email and username); so I looked at 

if (err.constraint === 'users_email_key') { return meaningful message}

or 

if (err.constraint === 'users_username_key') { return meaningful message}